# Calculate average column value per day

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have the following table structure: `Value` (stores random integer values), Datetime` (stores purchased orders datetimes).

How would I get the average value from all `Value` rows across a full day?

I'm assuming the query would be something like the following

```
SELECT  count(*) / 1
FROM  mytable
WHERE DateTime = date(now(), -1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a simple `AVG` task:

```
SELECT `datetime`,AVG(`Value`) as AvgValue
FROM TableName
GROUP BY `datetime`
```

To find average of a specific day:

```
SELECT `datetime`,AVG(`Value`) as AvgValue
FROM TableName
WHERE `datetime`=@MyDate
GROUP BY `datetime`
```

Or Simply:

```
SELECT AVG(`Value`) as AvgValue
FROM TableName
WHERE `datetime`=@MyDate
```

**Explanation:**

`AVG` is an aggregate function used to find the average of a column. Read more [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg).

Answer (score 9):

You can `GROUP BY` the `DATE` part of `DATETIME` and use `AVG` aggregate function to find an average value for each group :

```
SELECT AVG(`Value`)
     , DATE(`Datetime`)
FROM `mytable`
GROUP BY DATE(`Datetime`)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query will give you what u want..

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(thedate_field, '%Y-%m-%d') as theday, avg (value)
FROM mytable group by
DATE_FORMAT(thedate_field, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try It its work...

```
Select AVG(value),convert(nvarchar,DateTime,103) from table group by convert(nvarchar,DateTime,103)
```