# mySql get N records in range

Tags: mysql, select, limit, sampling

I have data logger acquiring temperatures aproximatly in 5 seconds interval (sometime data is missing like MQTT QoS 0). Each sample is stored in database with timestamp. That means 14400 records per day.

Now I want to show graph results in simple arduino based display with small memory. If I want to show weekly graph that means whooping 100800 records and of course I don't have memory to get that.

So is it possible to get for example N records from start timestamp to end timestamp linear spaced. Picking every x sample is not good option as records are not precise every 5 second. It may be just closest sample to interval but I prefer if it's possible to get average of interval.

For example I have already recorded 10 weeks. Now I want to show a past week with just a 7 records (one per day) and I wish to get average for each day as result. Is that possible at all?

Other example is that I want one minute average of last hour. (in one query!)

I do google but can't find solution.

p.s.
Current (working) solution is:

```
SELECT AVG(`sVal`), id, `timestamp` FROM `Test` WHERE sKey='U1'  AND timestamp between '2023-08-01 00:00:00' and '2023-08-30 23:59:00' GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`)/86400)
```

...but I'm afraid that it's not prone to linux timestamp year 2038 problem.

Comment: You can use `AVG(column) GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)` to get the daily average.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845116/calculate-average-column-value-per-day That was one of the first hits when I googled "mysql average by day"

Comment: Leading data visualisation tools can easily deal with this amount of data without any averaging or sampling. It could be easier to trust them rather than trying to figure out best sampling method.

Comment: this will return only 1 record - average per day. I want to get 7 records one per day in week.

Comment: `GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)` will return 1 record for each day, so 7 records for a week.

Comment: "I want" is not a question. Show what you tried, explain the problem, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: ahh I'm novice in SQL. I didn't understand AVG completly. If I want to get 100 avreges from 24 hours  I need tu use something similar to GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`)/864)

Comment: ... as I wish to query from time to time and number of records (averages) wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a single query. First, create a table of integers (which can be useful in many queries).  Something like this would be fine:

```
create table integers (
   i integer not null primary key
)
```

*For this query you only need to populate the table with integers from 0 to 6.*

For testing your readings, I created a table like this:

```
create table readings (
   ts timestamp not null primary key,
   reading float not null
)
```

My 'readings' table (only 3 days of data):

```
+---------------------+---------+
| ts                  | reading |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2023-08-01 00:00:00 |      13 |
| 2023-08-01 00:03:00 |      20 |
| 2023-08-01 00:06:00 |      22 |
| 2023-08-01 00:08:00 |      21 |
| 2023-08-01 00:11:00 |      19 |
| 2023-08-02 00:15:00 |      25 |
| 2023-08-02 19:15:00 |      14 |
| 2023-08-03 00:15:00 |       9 |
+---------------------+---------+
```

Using those two tables (readings and integers), this query will pull the daily average for one week starting on 2023-08-01:

```
with daterange as (
select date_add('2023-08-01 00:00:00', interval (i.i) day) as ts from 
   integers i
   where i between 0 and 6
   )
select daterange.ts, avg(reading) 
from readings r 
join daterange on r.ts between daterange.ts and date_add(daterange.ts, interval 1 day)
       group by daterange.ts
```

Results:

```
+---------------------+--------------+
| ts                  | avg(reading) |
+---------------------+--------------+
| 2023-08-01 00:00:00 |           19 |
| 2023-08-02 00:00:00 |         19.5 |
| 2023-08-03 00:00:00 |            9 |
+---------------------+--------------+
```